# How to authenticate/verify login credentials & check for user meta without logging in?

Tags: users, login, wp-login-form, authentication

I have custom login form and i used wp_signon() to authenticate. However, i wanted to run an additional check for **usermeta** and if the user has **account_status === pending**, throw an error or  or prevent them from getting logged in. How do i do that? I can't seem to find a filter

Comment: @Rup Thanks for the heads up, i missed the title when i was typing it. As i was saying, i plan to intercept any login authentication. I wanted to run a **usermeta check** to see if their **account_status** is pending or active. If it's active then continue to log them in and if not, throw an error and prevent them from logging in. Yes this is a custom login form and i used wp_signon() as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a low-priority [authenticate filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/authenticate/). I'm surprised there aren't more appropriate hooks in the login process, but I can't see one. (There is already an example of a filter like this though: [wp_authenticate_spam_check](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_authenticate_spam_check/).)

If the value the filter is given is a user, that means a previous filter has accepted the username & password. We can then perform our check and then either return the user if good or an error if not:

```php
function authenticate_reject_account_status_pending( $user, $username, $password ) {
    if ( $user instanceof WP_User ) {
        if ( $user[ 'account_status' ] === 'pending' ) {
            return new WP_Error( 'user_is_pending',
                __( 'Account is pending approval. Please contact support for help.' )
            );
        }
    }

    return $user;
}
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'authenticate_reject_account_status_pending', 999999, 3 );
```

I have not tested this, but the general pattern should work even if this code doesn't. This runs before the cookie is created etc.